# I can't pull polygon column from postgresql database with ssis

Tags: ssis, powerbi, etl, ssas, business-intelligence

[image: error image]

We have a Postgresql database, we have GIS software and we show the locations of the houses in a rectangular format on the map. When I try to pull data with SSIS, the geometry column gives an error. How can I overcome this problem? Do we have alternatives? (I have one SQL Server for DWH, I am pulling data from SSIS with ADO NET Source, can I use a different source?)

I created a view for myself and changed the type of the geometry column to different data types.